# Web API is rounding decimal values automatically

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, decimal, sqldatatypes

I'm using Dapper and trying to insert a decimal value on my database as you can see. The value is 7.5 but in database appears like 8.

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@ClientID", acc.ClientID);
parameters.Add("@Type", acc.Type);
parameters.Add("@Date", acc.Date);
parameters.Add("@Description", acc.Description);
parameters.Add("@Value", acc.Value, DbType.Decimal);
parameters.Add("@Balance", acc.Balance, DbType.Decimal);
parameters.Add("@Cancelled", acc.Cancelled);

conn.Execute(
    sql: Procedures.sp_AccountsInsert,
    param: parameters,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I wrote a file and I saw that acc.Value was 7.5 but after the execute, a rounded value 8 was stored on a database.

ID: 11 Value: **8.00** Balance: **4.00**

I thought the problem was from Dapper and I changed the project to pure AdoNet but the problem persists.

Comment: how is your stored procedure defined?

Comment: Please post the `sp_AccountsInsert` procedure and the table schema as well.

Comment: I found the solution! In my stored procedure i had the parameter defined like DECIMAL without (18,2) so it was rounding the value automatically. I added the (18,2) extra information and it works! Thanks btw @Jeremy

Comment: yup.always trace the data all the way through.